# Booking System Using C# winform

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

Someone can help?

How to change Buttons backcolor using database data. For example when I set particular button into reserved or already booked status the backcolor should change into red.

Comment: It's unclear what you've already tried, or which particular part is causing you problems. Are you already able to fetch the data from the database? Can you detect when something is booked? Is the problem actually in changing the color? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to establish a connection to your database using a `SQLConnection` object or the appropriate class depending on your database.

For instance:

```
bool isReserved;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT isReserved FROM YourTable WHERE BookingId = 1", connection))
{
    connection.Open();  
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            isReserved = (bool)reader["isReserved"];
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the `BackColor` property.

```
if (isReserved) {
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `id` of your button to be `Button1`, then you can do:

> Button1.BackColor = Color.Red